# How can I mock this with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs

How can I mock the line?

```
get base(): CrudController<Parametros> {
  return this;
}
```

```js
@Controller('parametros')
export class ParametrosController implements CrudController<Parametros>{
  private readonly msg: 'No se permite la operación para el rol del usuario.';
  
  constructor(
    public service: ParametrosService,
    public usuariosService: UsuariosService){}

  get base(): CrudController<Parametros> {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to mock it? What collaborator are you actually testing?

Answer (score 0):

You did not really provide the module but when you register the controller in the module you can get the reference of the instance so you can [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) it.

```js
app = await Test.createTestingModule({
    controllers: [ParametrosController],
  }).compile();

const controller = app.get<ParametrosController>(ParametrosController);
const mock = jest.spyOn(controller, 'base', 'get').mockReturnValue({hmm: 123});

expect(controller.base).toEqual({hmm: 123});
expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

spyOne function accepts `accessType` as a 3rd parameter, so you can pass `get` when it is a getter.